# How to grab information from multiple php uploaded files

Tags: php, upload, associative-array

**EDIT**: got it working, but could still use help. Please see below in edit section.

I've searched all over, but this is really confusing me.

I have a form that allows for multiple file uploads. Each file input is named "track[]" so that way it can get associated into an array. When the form is submitted, I set the file information into an array here:

```
private $tracks = [];

public function setTracks () {

        $length = count($_FILES['track']['name']);

        for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        $this->tracks[$i] = ["file_temp" => $_FILES['track']['tmp_name'][$i],
                            "file_name" => $_FILES['track']['name'][$i],
                            "file_size" => $_FILES['track']['size'][$i],
                            "file_type" => $_FILES['track']['type'][$i],
                            "target_path" => "tracks/" . $_FILES['track']['name'][$i],
                            "file_error" => $_FILES['track']['error'][$i]];
        }

    }
```

This creates the array just fine, but I'm finding it difficult trying to actually save the file by getting the information I need from this array.

This is my rather basic method for uploading images. How can I adapt this for uploading tracks?

```
 public function uploadImg () {

        if ($this->file_size > $this->img_max_size) {
            echo "The file size is too large. Please compress it and try again.";         
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($this->file_temp, "../../" . $this->target_path)) {
            echo "The image ".  $this->file_name . " has been uploaded successfully!"; 
        } 
        else {
            echo $this->file_error . "There was an error uploading the image, please try again!";
        }

    }
```

By the way, I think a foreach loop would be better in both my setTracks and my new uploadTracks methods I'm trying to make, rather than the for loop I am currently implementing, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use one in this case.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure exactly what I did, but I got this to work. Still, if somebody could help me change my for loop to a foreach it would be greatly appreciated. Here's my method that handles the upload:

```
public function uploadTrack () {

    $length = count($this->tracks);

    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {

        if ($this->file_size > $this->track_max_size) {
            echo "The file size is too large. Please compress it and try again.";      
        } 

    else if (move_uploaded_file($this->tracks[$i]["file_temp"], "../../" . $this->tracks[$i]['target_path'])) {
        echo "The image ".  $this->file_name . " has been uploaded successfully!"; 
    } 
    else {
        echo $this->file_error . "There was an error uploading the image, please try again!";
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You will have to do $_FILES['track['.$i.']']... try echo $_FILES['track['.$i.']']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Wouldn't you wan't to do `$this->tracks[0]["file_temp"]` ?

Comment: @BLE I tried doing this in my new uploadTrack method, but I get nothing back. I tried var dumping and it came back as empty (string(0) "" )

Comment: @akshaykhale even if I just do echo $_FILES['track[0]']['tmp_name']; it gives me "Notice: Undefined index: track[0]"

Comment: try using foreach loop instead of indexed for loop eg. foreach($_FILES as $file_to_upload) { ... } and then perform your operations on $file_to_upload

Comment: @akshaykhale something like this? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to make this foreach loop https://jsfiddle.net/heg28z47/

Comment: _“If I try to echo `$this->tracks["file_temp"][0]` It comes back as an undefined index”_ – of course it does, because you put the two indices the wrong way around …